# mysql index issue-explain says file sort

Tags: mysql, explain

i have very simple mysql table with 5 columns but 5 million data. earlier when data was less my server load was very less but now the load is increasing as the data is more than 5 million and i expect it to reach 10 million by this year end so server will be more slow.i have used indexed wisely

structure is very simple with id as auto increment and  primary key and i am filtering the data based on id only which is automatically indexed as it is primary key(i tried indexing it as well but no benefit)

table A

```
   id   pid   title     app   get
```

my query is

```
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4061280 , 10
```

and explain says

```
 id      select_type    table    type   possible_keys   key    key_len    ref   rows            Extra
 1        SIMPLE       tableA    ALL      NULL         NULL      NULL     NULL  4700461       Using filesort
```

i dont want to go through all rows as it will slow down my server and create heavy load for file sorting as it will create temporary files either in buffer or in disc.

please advice any good idea to solve this issue.

when my id is indexed why it will go through all rows and reach to desired row.it can not jump directly to that row????

Comment: how do you know that you need the data from the 400000th page?

Comment: I mean, it is usually useless to let users go so far. Those who really need it, would appreciate just export-the-whole-set functionality

Comment: @newtover it may be  random page or user might have entered with search engine so he is in 4000000 page you will show him next 10 only not first page

Comment: no user is usually interested in it, people just click there to see whether the system breaks.

Comment: @newtover I am surprized to see ur reputation 10000 + and u dont understand the basic.if u want to grow u have to deal with big databases and that issue must be sorted out

Comment: have you seen an option to look at the 40000th page in google? Even most social netwoks now start limiting your ability to look deep into history. People don't need to go to the page 40005, they usually want to see data for a particular tag or date

Comment: @chetna123 it's more trouble when you see "Using temporary; using filesort";   LIMITS with large offset are bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have "gaps" (read deleted records) in your id..

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id > 4061279 and id <= 4061290 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Ok next

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id <= 4061290 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: gap is there else your idea was superb